# Executing Shell Script from PHP. Apache log Syntax Error: ")" unexpected

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, syntax-error

I can't find the error, the scripts runs fine from console, I thought it was PHP thing but couldn't fine anything.

Maybe permissions things? Exec things? I really don't know much, hope someone can help me. Thanks!

BASH Script (SIMPLY SENDS A JOB TO A PRINTER, but I put it enterely just in case):

```
#!/bin/bash
PBOX_DIR_TMP="/tmp"
DESDE=$1
HASTA=$2
FORMULARIO=$3
COLA=$4
FECHA=$(date +%F)
SPOOL="/spool.$$.txt"
ARCHIVOSALIDA="${PBOX_DIR_TMP}"/salida.$$.txt
RETURNCODE=0
echo "$DESDE"
echo "$HASTA"
echo "@PBSSFORM ${FORMULARIO}" > "${SPOOL}"
for ((i = ${DESDE};i <= ${HASTA};i++))
do
  if [ $i > ${DESDE} ]
  then
    echo -e "\f${FECHA}" >> "${SPOOL}"
    echo "${i}" >> "${SPOOL}"
  else
    echo "${FECHA}" >> "${SPOOL}"
    echo "${i}" >> "${SPOOL}"
  fi
done
cat "${SPOOL}" | pboxsvc ${PBOX_DIR_BIN}/pboxlib.bin AplicarHostForm > "${ARCHIVOSALIDA}"
lp -d "${COLA}" "${ARCHIVOSALIDA}"
RETURNCODE=$?
rm "${ARCHIVOSALIDA}"
rm "${SPOOL}"
if [ ${RETURNCODE} -eq 0 ]
  then
    exit 1
  else
    exit 0
fi
```

PHP call:

```
$cmd = "/printb/imprimirFormPlano.bin 1 2 FILE.PS Cola1";
```

Apache Log:

```
/printb/imprimirFormPlano.bin 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
sh: 2: not found.
```

The scripts works if I call it from shell like this: `./printb/imprimirFormPlano.bin 1 2 FILE.PS Cola1`

Comment: what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I need to call it from PHP. It will be web based

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your apache's default shell is `sh` rather than `bash`. Try changing your command to

```
$cmd = '/bin/bash /printb/imprimirFormPlano.bin 1 2 FILE.PS Cola1';
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives different output in apache's error log: /printb/imprimirFormPlano.bin: Cannot execute binary file. sh: 2: not found (I converted it to bin from .sh)

Comment: @NullUserException Sorry it's encripted the one that converts to bin.

Comment: @Jorge Why do you need to make this conversion? Why can't you just call the .sh file itself?

Comment: @NullUserException I don't know it's my works politic. I tried using the sh with PHP but gives me access errors to locations (maybe user problem). The strange thing is that the error is like this: `/spool.4234.txt Access denied` is like if its trying to save on `/` instead of `/temp/`.